# how to get the selected values from a drop down list in cake php

Tags: cakephp, drop-down-menu

I’m new to cake php. I need to get the user selected value from a drop down list in cake php. my view code is :

```
echo $this->Form->create('order');
echo $this->Form->input('status', array('options' => $options, 'default' => '--Select--'));
```

please help me to get the values(not key).

Comment: Set the key the same as the value, that way you will get the same output the user selects.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get the user selected value into your controller's method using:

```
$selected_value = $this->request->data['order']['status'];
```

You can either check the posted data into your controller's method using:

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
{
   pr($this->request->data);die;
   $selected_value = $this->request->data['order']['status'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
'options' => array('Appartment', 'Villa' , 'Residential' ,'Kiosk', 'Commercial'),
'empty' => '(choose one)'
```

Comment: how to get the selected value sir??

Comment: above code is working for me but you can do like this also....=> $usernames = array_combine($usernames, $usernames);