# How to retrieve a value from a query string that stems from a <select> form input?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I simply need to get the selected value from a query string. Currently I just get the index of the list and not the actual value. I cant use Post as I need the value for a pagination search.

I dont get an error but just the number of the index of the list returned. The answer must be simple and I have tried many combinations. I have tried `['Student']` in front of the query as well.

I just couldnt see the answer in the docs and previous posts on this topic didnt work for me either. I am stuck.

The query string has a number {url}students/myindex5?address_suburb=1 //suburb should be a string and it appears as a string in the drop down list

```
public function myindex5() {

    $this->set('filterSuburb', $this->Student->find('list', array(
        'fields' => array('Student.address_suburb')
    )));

    $havefilter = false;        
    $tsub = $this->request->query['address_suburb'];  
    // $tsub = array_combine($tsub, $tsub);//didnt work
    debug($tsub); //I just get the index value of the list

    if (!empty($tsub)) {
        // ...
```

View

```
echo $this->Form->create('Student', array(
    'type' => 'get',
    'url' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'myindex5')
));
echo $this->Form->input('address_suburb', array(
    'options' => $filterSuburb,
    'empty' => '(choose one)')
);
echo $this->Form->end('Search');
```

For reference

- **[how to get the selected values from a drop down list in cake php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909899/how-to-get-the-selected-values-from-a-drop-down-list-in-cake-php)**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html**

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you'd add a sample of the query string in question. People tend to be lazy, they don't want to waste their time figuring out what kind of query your form may produce, even though it might be obvious to some.

Comment: You need to check if form is submitted or not using request isPost function. Also check `var_dump($this->request->data);`.

Comment: The query string has a number  {url}students/myindex5?address_suburb=1

Comment: I am using GET and not a POST. I cant use POST as I am using pagination.   echo $this->Form->create('Student', array('type' => 'get','url' => array('controller' => 'students', 'action' => 'myindex5' )));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `select` input, the value send is the value of the `option` tag:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

If I choose "Option 1", you will get 1, not "Option 1".

If you want to change the `value` attribute, you need to set something else to the `FormHelper::input` method `options` parameter, something like:

```
array(
    'value1' => 'Text 1',
    /** etc. **/
);
```

If you want your value to be ids of Student, just change your `find` call to:

```
$this->set('filterSuburb', $this->Student->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Student.id', 'Student.address_suburb')
)));
```

If you look at `find('list')` [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), you'll see this:

> When calling find('list'), the fields passed are used to determine what should be used as the array key and value, and optionally what to group the results by.

So passing `Student.id` and `Student.address_suburb` will output a select with `Student.id` as `option` value and `Student.address_suburb` as `option` text.

If you want something else than `Student.id`, just change it in the `find('list')` call, you can even change it to have `option` like `<option value="redcliff">redcliff</option>` (same value and text), by doing:

```
$this->set('filterSuburb', $this->Student->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Student.address_suburb', 'Student.address_suburb')
)));
```

Comment: I dont want any id's at all, I just want the option value and option text to be strings so I am still confused as how to set this up as I need to pass the string. For example I have 'redcliff' as a suburb I select and I pass this name as well. I will check the docs you posted

Comment: @ajt Actually you want all your option to be like `<option value="redcliff">redcliff</option>` to be able to directly get `redcliff` in your controller?

Comment: I know your right, I just cant see what to change as you have listed options value and I use a variable, you also mention id's. I am unsure what I am to change sorry.

Comment: @ajt Just tell me what field of student you want to retrieve in `myindex5` action?

Comment: Student.address_suburb  as this is the suburbs I want to pass as a filter and I want to select the suburb and have this returned. $tsub = $this->request->query['address_suburb']; should return a string which is the suburb name but it doesnt

Comment: @ajt Ok, I've updated my answer (see the end), you normally just have to change `Student.id` to `Student.address_suburb` in the `find('list')` field parameter to get what you want.

Comment: well done, there is no way I could have deduced this from the docs.